# WSGIRequest object has no attribute 'subdomain'

Tags: python, django

I am working on this project which by the way was fine until a seconds ago. I added a generic detailview in one of the application views which threw me `Template not found error`, though I clearly indicated the template_name and  made sure the template exists. I refreshed the page and **BAM** I got this server error.

The traceback indicated two files and following are the code snippets:

general_views.py

```
def server_error_view(request, template_name='other/500.html', **kwargs):
    return render_to_response(template_name, 4, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

context_processors.py

```
def applications(request):
    if request.subdomain is not None: #This is where the error occured
        subdomain = str(request.subdomain)+'_'
    else:
        subdomain = ''
```

and middleware.py

```
class SubdomainMiddleware:
""" Make the subdomain publicly available to classes """    
def process_request(self, request):
    domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
    if (len(domain_parts) > 3):
        subdomain = domain_parts[0]
        if (subdomain.lower() == 'www'):
            subdomain = domain_parts[1]
        else:
            subdomain = None
        domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[2:])
    elif (len(domain_parts) > 2):
        subdomain = domain_parts[0]
        if (subdomain.lower() == 'www'):
            subdomain = None
        domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[1:])
    else:
        subdomain = None
        domain = request.get_host()
    request.subdomain = subdomain
    request.domain = domain
```

The complete Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
return callback(request, **param_dict)
File "/home/project/hris/views/general_views.py", line 37, in server_error_view
return render_to_response(template_name, 4, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 176, in __init__
self.update(processor(request))
File "/home/project/hris/context_processors.py", line 17, in applications
print request.subdomain
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'subdomain'
```

Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
#     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # tracking
    'tracking.middleware.VisitorTrackingMiddleware',
    'tracking.middleware.VisitorIPTrackingMiddleware',
    # tracking end
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # my custom middleware:

    'project.middleware.SubdomainMiddleware',


# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
# 'django_pdb.middleware.PdbMiddleware',
```

)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # default context processors
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    # custom context processors
    "hris.context_processors.applications",
    "hris.context_processors.organization_context",
)
```

Comment: Try printing your request right before the error to check if the subdomain is being setted.

Comment: Please post the traceback. Also, did you add your `SubDomainMiddleware` class to the middleware settings?

Comment: It doesnot print anything, since im on my localhost right now and yes the SubDomainMiddleware is already included in the middleware settings. I have updated the question with full traceback. Please spare some time to help.

Comment: Also inculde the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings

Comment: Which of your code snippets (if any) is an `context_processor` from traceback?

Comment: I have updated the question with the correct filenames and the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. Please go through it.

Comment: Please add context processors settings also.

Comment: Dear Mr. Rahul, I've added the context processors too. Please have a look.

Comment: Try putting a debugger and see if the code for setting `subdomain` attribute is being run. One workaround for the error(not the solution though) is to replace `if request.subdomain is None:` with `if hasattr(request, 'subdomain', None):`.

Comment: Also, whats the usage of `4`  in `render_to_response()`. The `context` should be dictionary.  I think you might have incorrect signature for `render_to_response`.  On a side note, you can use `render()` which by default uses `RequestContext`.

Comment: `render()` didnt help. I copied the whole project in another directory and its working now. But I literally couldnt sleep better because I still have no freaking idea about the error. This is frustrating.